# How to show a message before executing a MATLAB built-in function

Tags: matlab

For some reasons, I need to show a message each time `save` function is executed. All the code of my program is already written. That's why I want to override the `save`MATLAB built-in function.

This is the function:

```
function save(varargin)
    disp(['The file has been saved to ' varargin{1}])
    builtin('save',varargin{:})
end
```

However, it doesn't work and MATLAB returns `Error using save`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming `varargin` is cell array of strings, as in the built-in function `save`.
The problem is that your version of `save` doesn't "know" the variables of the caller function. You can use `evalin` function to evaluate `save` in the context of the caller function.
In order to do so, you should convert `varargin` to strings. One way to do so is

```
function save(varargin)
    disp(['The file has been saved to ' varargin{1}])
    cmd = ['builtin(''save'',' sprintf(repmat('''%s'',',1,nargin),varargin{:}) ];
    cmd(end) = ')';
    evalin('caller',cmd)
end
```

Comment: The `repmat` is superfluous here - `sprintf('''%s'',', ,varargin{:})` will achieve the same result since `sprintf` will repeat the format string until all inputs that match it are consumed.